# Docker Containers in Production - How-to

Tags: docker

I just have some questions because I want to start to use Docker.

We are a small team and we develop some apps to different clients (they are small apps like for 20 users) we have a couple of servers (Windows Server 2016 and Red Hat) and mostly we develop the applications with Node/Express and React. My question is: What is the simplest way to mount MERN stack application to production with Docker?

I've been looking for tutorials and almost all of them are with Digital Ocean, AWS, using CI with Travis and Github, etc. So its basically run the container on the server and thats it? It's necessary Docker Enterprise, Kubernetes or Swarm? Right now we have the apps running with pm2 on the server and using nginx as reverse proxy. Basically we want to check if it works with us the simple way to start learning more advance stuff later.

What I want to do is have like an nginx container running and different containers from different apps in our Windows Server and each time is a new release from one of our apps somehow grab our code from Gitlab and send them to production (the containers).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: A question focused on a more specific area of deployment would be easier to answer.  I'll note that the words, "mount", "production", and "Docker" don't usually go together but that a more standard workflow involves building immutable Docker images, so you deploy the images but don't need to separately deploy the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all install docker on your servers: windows or Linux have their own versions.
then run Nginx container from  docker hub that has different tag used default latest tag and expose nginx port to see from outside network.
Also create docker file of your application to build an image base on it.
Now you can deploy your app on nginx. on the other hand you need a database container to connect your app to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available based upon cloud deployments or your own organization platform.

**Cloud Deplyoment**

If want to go ahead with cloud deployment for scalability, availability, networking, security and what not cloud provides, here are your options based on AWS/Kubernetes/Openshift/Docker, you can also look for AZURE/GCP etc as an AWS alternative-

1. Simply use [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/), this is container orchestration service by AWS, will act as [PaaS](https://www.stratoscale.com/blog/kubernetes/ec2-container-service-vs-kubernetes/)
2. Use [AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) , recommended for application with heavy load and transactions etc. Here AWS manages [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) nodes. You really don't have to worry about kubernetes infra setup. Knowledge of Kubernetes console is required to deploy containers
3. Use public cloud like AWS/AZURE/GCP for [IaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service) and deploy [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/)/[Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/)/[Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/) for container orchestration. Here you need to take care of IaaS and PaaS installation and management.
4. you can also use cloud provider managed PaaS solutions for ex - [Openshift Dedicated](https://www.openshift.com/products/dedicated/)

You can also look out for other PaaS and IaaS solutions apart from the above described.

**Own Infra Deployment**

If you already have organization infrastructure available, which I suppose you do, go ahead and setup PaaS solution using-

1. [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)
2. [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/#production-environment)
3. [Openshift Container Platform](https://www.openshift.com/products/container-platform) or Opensource version [OKD](https://www.okd.io/)

You can also lookout for other container orchestration solutions apart from described above.

Now lets talk about

**Infra Setup as code**-
Plenty of options available, [choose based on your need](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/chef-ansible-puppet-terraform), I personally like Terraform since I can *setup and manage the state* of AWS/AZURE/GCP resources, Kubernetes etc using terraform as a code

**CICD**
For this you can always use Jenkins/TravisCI etc as a docker image, and run on PaaS solution of your choice, integrate with Repositories for notifications/Polling/Hooks etc and build/push/deploy your containers from the code to specific environments. 
You can also use [Openshift S2I features](https://blog.openshift.com/create-s2i-builder-image/) or public cloud pipelines as an alternative.